# Abut SVM Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) on Pregel-like BSP model

Tags: svm, bsp

May I ask whether anyone else have also look into the SGD mapping on BSP model? I'm investigating whether BSP model is a good candidate for implementing distributed version of SVM SGD.

Thanks!
Joe